# Easy to use tool for editing database. Easy to modify like django admin

Tags: database-administration

Is there a tool that I can give a few people access to so that they can quickly modify the contents of our database?  I'm looking for something easy to use and general purpose.

phppgadmin is going to be too complicated for some of the people that will be using it.  I really like the django admin, but some of the constraints that Django brings are unacceptable.  Something functionally similar would be great, I really do like how it works.

Comment: You might want to explicitly state what your database is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your tried using open office? you can get the postgresql driver here: http://dba.openoffice.org/drivers/postgresql/index.html

the you can create a quick form for anyone to add/delete query the database really easy.

and it's FREE to boot!!

Answer (score 0):

I really like EMS's tools: http://www.sqlmanager.net/

They have for various RDBMSs, but they might be too complex for your intended use case.

You really need to state your platform and actual intended use (for instance, why is Django admin unacceptable?)

Comment: Django wants to add tables to the database, and puts constraints on primary keys.  I don't want to have to modify the structure of the database which I don't want to do as this is the database holding info on our radio station's music.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [squirrel-sql](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/).